# Please explain the repeated gradient of a function on manifold.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

[image]
How to calculate the following expressions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Where is this from? I am not following the notations, how does the first covariant derivative drop the Christoffel symbol?

Comment: What's your question? It's just "How to calculate the following expressions?" Which expressions? The ones from the picture? What have you tried? I'm not understanding your question at all.

Comment: Even if the question were to ask us to explain what was going on in the picture, please try to point out exactly what you're not understanding, and perhaps say how the Christoffel symbols were defined in your books.

Comment: I am not understanding the $(\nabla^{2}u)_{i,j}=\partial_{i,j}u-\Gamma_{i,j}^{k}\partial_{k}u$, and how the k-th covarient derivative is defined?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $T\colon \mathfrak{X}(M)^k \to \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ is a covariant $k$-tensor and $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, one defines $$(\nabla_XT)(X_1,\ldots,X_k) = X(T(X_1,\ldots, X_k)) - \sum_{k=1}^n T(X_1,\ldots, \nabla_XX_i,\ldots,X_k),$$thinking of a product rule. If $u$ is a smooth function, $u$ can be seen as a $0$-tensor and the above definition applies to give $\nabla_Xu  = X(u) = {\rm d}u(X)$. Now $(\nabla u)(X) = {\rm d}u(X)$ is a $1$-tensor, and the definition again applies to give $$(\nabla^2u)(X,Y) \doteq (\nabla_X(\nabla u))(Y) = X({\rm d}u(Y))- {\rm d}u(\nabla_XY).$$In coordinates $(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$, take $X = \partial_i$ and $Y = \partial_j$ to obtain $$(\nabla^2u)_{ij} = \partial_i(\partial_ju) - \Gamma_{ij}^k \partial_ku.$$For $\nabla^3u$, you repeat what was done above for the $2$-tensor $\nabla^2u$.